# xcode 4.4.1 mistreats svn working copy as git

Tags: xcode, git, svn, xcode4

I add a svn repository in Xcode organizer, then use xcode to check out an project folder, then in xcode's menu->file->source control, it shows "commit","push","pull","merge" instead of svn commands. 
If I use "commit", it shows that all files are not under version control(with a question mark in front of the file)
If I use pull/push/merge, it say there are local uncommitted change.

I'm wondering how to make Xcode know that this is a svn working copy, not a git one.'

PS:I use xcode Version 4.4.1.

**Edit**

I found something strange, I remove all the references in xcode repository management which is in xcode organizer. Then, every time I checkout an subversion repository, xcode creates a reference to a git repository whose path is at my home directory(the location of that git repository is /Users/my_name).
So I think that xcode treats my whole home directory as a git working copy(or a repository?).
I changed to another user and solved the problem.

But question remains, why xcode treats my home dirctory as a git repository? There is only a file called .gitmodules that may have anything to do with git in my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to another user, and its OK now.